# wsimport : unable to rename the package name

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, wsimport

I've a wsdl at an address like
https://mycompany.com/mywspath/Documents.svc?wsdl
It seems that xsd is visible at 
https://mycompany.com/mywspath/Documents.svc?wsdl&xsd=xsd0

giving a

```
wsimport https://mycompany.com/mywspath/Documents.svc?wsdl
```

I obtain hierararchy containing the classes related to Documents and the dependencies (com.microsoft,...)

```
com
-microsoft
--...
-mycompany
--...
org
-datacontract
--schemas
---...
```

My willing is to refactor the generated clasees in com.mycompany.mywspath to com.mycompany.mywspath.test or com.mycompany.mywspathA

This because there are other webservice that contain other definitions in the same namespace so the generated classes are stored in the same package com.mycompany.mywspath and the ObjectFactory.class obtained from the first wsimport is overwritten from the one generated from the following calls.

My willing is to avoid this binding on different packages the namespace coming from different webservices using -b  option of wsimport.

I used a XML binding file like this:

```
 <jxb:bindings 
        jxb:version="2.1"  
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"   
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">

        <bindings schemaLocation="https://https://mycompany.com/mywspath/Documents.svc?xsd=xsd0"
                node="//xsd:schema[@targetNamespace='http://mycompany.com/mywspath']">
            <jxb:schemaBindings>
                <jxb:package name="com.mycompany.mywspath"/>
            </jxb:schemaBindings>
        </bindings>

    </jxb:bindings>
```

Class are originated in the same place without any modification and com/mycompany/mywspath/test is not originated.

How can I move those classes to com/mycompany/mywspath/test package ?

Comment: You have changed `<jxb:package name="com.mycompany.mywspath"/>`?

Comment: What do you mean with "you have changed ... ?"  ?

Comment: I mean change `package name="com.mycompany.mywspath"` to `package name="com.mycompany.mywspath.test"`

Comment: yes, all the classes are stil generated in com.mycompany.mywspath instead of com.mycompany.mywspath.test

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
wsimport -p com.bingo.charlie YOUR_WSDL_URL
```

to define a package for your generated files.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wsimport -b binding.xml` to change the package for the generated files.

Source: [configure target packages](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Configure-Target-Packages-in-Binding-Files)